# i'm getting unexpected behavior using realloc

Tags: c, visual-studio-2019, realloc

for some reason, every 2-3 times that i run the program i get unexpected values, such as -842150451 -842150451, and every other time i get the correct result: 7 9.

i'm a student, so sorry if the code is a little academic.

please see code:

```
int mat[ROW][COL] = {
    {2,-3,5,1,2},
    {2,4,7,7,1},
    {1,9,7,3,0}
};

int row, col, tempRow = 0, tempCol = 0, indexCol, indexRow = 0, loopTempRow, flag = 0, cnt = 1, loopTempCol = 0;
int* arr;
int* ptrArr;

arr = (int*)malloc(cnt * sizeof(int)); // mallocating an array with size 1 * int
ptrArr = arr;

if (arr == NULL)    // checking allocation done succefully
{
    printf("Error Allocating Memory\n");
    exit(1);
}


for (row = 0; row < ROW; row++) // starting from row 0 we will wheck col 0,1,2,3,4 for the highest val.
{
    flag = 1;
    tempCol = 0;

    for (col = 0; col < COL; col++)
    {
        if (mat[row][col] > tempCol)
        {
            tempCol = mat[row][col];
            indexCol = col;
        }
    }
    for (loopTempRow = 0; loopTempRow < ROW; loopTempRow++) // then we will check the row of the col index
    {

        if (mat[loopTempRow][indexCol] > tempCol)
        {
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (flag == 1)
    {
        cnt++;                                                      // this is a counter for realloctaing.
        arr = realloc(arr, (cnt - 1) * sizeof(int));                            // every iteration the arr is increasing by 1
        printf("mat[%d][%d] = %d\n", row, indexCol, mat[row][indexCol]);
        *ptrArr = mat[row][indexCol];                                       // inserting the element into the arr
        ptrArr++;
    }
}

if (cnt == 1)                                           // if the cnt = 1, it means that flag didn't became 1. which meant no value inserted to the arr
    arr = NULL;




for (ptrArr = arr; ptrArr - arr < cnt - 1; ptrArr++)                        // print arr
    printf("%d\t", *ptrArr);

free(arr);
```

}

i suspect that the problem is with the realloc block:

```
if (flag == 1)
    {
        cnt++;                                                      // this is a counter for realloctaing.
        arr = realloc(arr, (cnt - 1) * sizeof(int));                            // every iteration the arr is increasing by 1
        printf("mat[%d][%d] = %d\n", row, indexCol, mat[row][indexCol]);
        *ptrArr = mat[row][indexCol];                                       // inserting the element into the arr
        ptrArr++;
    }
}
```

Comment: so, remove the `- 1`

Comment: `cnt++` and `cnt - 1`? You increase the value of `cnt` by one, but then you use the old value of `cnt` for the reallocation.

Comment: The value -842150451 suggests you're reading uninitialized allocated heap memory.

Comment: And `if (cnt == 1) arr = NULL;` means you will have a memory leak. I think you need to sit down after a good night sleep, and rethink the logic about `arr` and how you handle it and its reallocations.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, thank you for your advice. one of the task i need to do is that if there is no value, then i need to return NULL to arr. that was the task. cnt will increase only when a condition is met. i initated cnt with 1, because i used for malloc.

Comment: Could you please explain what this snippet is supposed to do (output given a certain input, logic steps of the algorithm)?

Comment: @Bob__, yes, it suppose to find the highest value in a row, and then check if it also the highest in the col. if yes, send the value to a dynamic allocated array. if there is no value, then send a NULL pointer to the malloced array.

Comment: What do you mean by "if there is no value, then send a NULL pointer to the malloced array"  ? The confusing part is "if there is no value". Do you mean "if the highest value in a row is not the highest value in its column" ?

Comment: @chmike, yes. You are correct. Sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initially allocate an array with room for one integer, but you never set that integer value. I guess it is because allocating a block of 0 bytes returned NULL which you assume is an error.

---

Another confusing code fragment is

```c
cnt++;                                       // this is a counter for realloctaing.
arr = realloc(arr, (cnt - 1) * sizeof(int)); // every iteration the arr is increasing by 1
```

Why initializing `cnt` to 1 if you want that the size of the allocated array is the number of times we had `flag == 1` ?

Beside, you never write any value in this array. Assigning a value to `*ptrArr` would at best overwrite the first value of the array.

---

Another problem it that you initially copy `arr` to `ptrArr`. Later, if `flag == 1` you reallocate `arr`. A reallocation implies that the input array may be deallocated (free) and a new bigger block is allocated. In this case, when you later assign a value to `*ptrArr` you won’t write in `arr`. You will write in deallocated space where you should not write. Worse, if that space is reallocated in the mean time, you may override valid data by mistake, which is a very nasty problem to debug.

I have the impression that you assume that reallocation creates space in front of the block. That is not correct. ralloc, extends the block. So room is added at the end of the block when its size grows.

This implies that you have to *append* `mat[row][indexCol]` to the array `arr` when `flag == 1`.

---

Here is how you should handle your array.

```c
// initialize the array as empty
int cnt = 0;
int *arr = NULL;
```

Note that allocating a block of 0 bytes is implementation dependent. It may or may not return NULL. Here we decide that an empty array is NULL and has `cnt == 0`.

The following code appends the value `mat[row][indexCol]` to the array:

```c
// append mat[row][indexCol] to the array arr
arr = realloc(arr, (cnt+1)*sizeof(int));
arr[cnt++] = mat[row][indexCol];
```

This works when `arr` is NULL because realloc will allocate a new block.

To print all values in the array:

```c
for(int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    printf("%d\t", arr[i]);
```

It doesn’t matter if `arr == NULL` when `cnt == 0` because `arr` is never accessed when `cnt == 0`.

---

There is also a mistake in the code that locates the biggest value in a row.

You initialize `tempCol` with 0, and compare values with it. If the row contains only negative values that are all smaller than 0, your algorithm will fail to find the biggest value in the row.

In order to find the biggest value in a row, you have two options.

1. Initialize tempCol with the smallest possible value : INT_MIN (#include <limits.h>).
2. Use the following code that removes the need of `tempCol`.

```c
indexCol = 0;
for (col = 1; col < COL; col++)
    if (mat[row][col] > mat[row][indexCol])
        indexCol = col;
// here, indexCol is the index of biggest value in the row
```

Comment: Dear chmike, thank you very much for your detailed and professional help. indeed, it seems to be that the problem was the ptrArr. i certainly learned a lot from your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is mostly likely due to using `ptrAtr`. You initialise it to the start of `arr`, but later on you `realloc` `arr` and there is no guarantee that `arr` will remain at the same memory location which means that `ptrArr` will no longer point into it.

You'd be better off with using an index into `arr` like this..

```
int cnt = 0;
arr = (int*)malloc(cnt * sizeof(int));

// stuff happens

if (flag == 1)
    {
        arr = realloc(arr, (cnt + 1) * sizeof(int));
        printf("mat[%d][%d] = %d\n", row, indexCol, mat[row][indexCol]);
        arr[cnt++] = mat[row][indexCol];
    }
}
```